# Join той же таблицы в Django ORM

Tags: sql, django

Есть две модели - `Покупатель` и `Заказ`:

```
class Customer(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Order(models.Model):
    SHOP_1, SHOP_2, SHOP_3 = 1, 2, 3
    SHOP_CHOICES = (
        (SHOP_1, 'Shop 1'),
        (SHOP_2, 'Shop 2'),
        (SHOP_3, 'Shop 3'),
    )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='orders')
    shop = models.IntegerField(choices=SHOP_CHOICES)
    updated_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    price = models.DecimalField()
```

Надо по каждому пользователю вывести последние заказы по каждому магазину. То есть из этого:

```
Customer
+-----+----------+
| id  | username |
+-----+----------+
| 1   | Garry    |
| ... | ...      |
+-----+----------+

Order
+-----+-------------+------+---------------------+-------+
| id  | customer_id | shop | updated_dt          | price |
+-----+-------------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 1   | 1           | 1    | 2017-07-01 00:00:00 | 12    |
| 2   | 1           | 1    | 2017-07-02 00:00:00 | 23    |
| 3   | 1           | 2    | 2017-07-01 00:00:00 | 35    |
| 4   | 1           | 2    | 2017-07-02 00:00:00 | 23    |
| 5   | 1           | 2    | 2017-07-03 00:00:00 | 93    |
| 6   | 1           | 3    | 2017-07-04 00:00:00 | 230   |
| ... | ...         | ...  | ...                 | ...   |
+-----+-------------+------+---------------------+-------+
```

Надо получить это:

```
+-----+-------------+------+---------------------+-------+
| id  | customer_id | shop | updated_dt          | price |
+-----+-------------+------+---------------------+-------+
| 2   | 1           | 1    | 2017-07-02 00:00:00 | 23    |
| 5   | 1           | 2    | 2017-07-03 00:00:00 | 93    |
| 6   | 1           | 3    | 2017-07-04 00:00:00 | 230   |
+-----+-------------+------+---------------------+-------+
```

Есть идея реализовать данный вывод через `join` таблицы заказов к этой же таблице:

```
SELECT 
  order1.*
FROM order order1
  LEFT JOIN order order2 ON (order1.shop = order2.shop
                             AND order1.updated_dt < order2.updated_dt
                             AND order1.customer_id = order2.customer_id)
WHERE stat2.id IS NULL AND stat1.customer_id = 1;
```

Но, насколько я понимаю, в `Django` нельзя явно `join`'ить таблицы.

Comment: [похожий вопрос в английской версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271835/left-join-django-orm)

Answer (score 0):

Несколько лет не аботал с django. Раньше это делалось так:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    SHOP_1, SHOP_2, SHOP_3 = 1, 2, 3
    SHOP_CHOICES = (
        (SHOP_1, 'Shop 1'),
        (SHOP_2, 'Shop 2'),
        (SHOP_3, 'Shop 3'),
    )

    customer = models.ForeignKey('Order', related_name='orders')
    shop = models.IntegerField(choices=SHOP_CHOICES)
    updated_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Я же привел точно такой же код модели в самом начале вопроса. Я спрашиваю, как составить правильно запрос.

Comment: я подумал с форейн кеем проблемы)

Answer (score 0):

Есть наивный вариант:

```
Order
.object
.filter(customer__id=1)
.values("shop")
.annotate(
    id=Max("id"), 
    customer_id=Max("customer_id"), 
    updated_dt=Max("updated_dt")
)
```

В данном случае мы сначала делаем группировку по магазину, а далее выбираем максимальную дату и оборачиваем все остальные колонки в аггрегирующие функции.

Работа с аггрегированием описанна в документации:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses

> If the values() clause precedes the annotate(), the annotation will be
>   computed using the grouping described by the values() clause.
>
> However, if the annotate() clause precedes the values() clause, the
>   annotations will be generated over the entire query set. In this case,
>   the values() clause only constrains the fields that are generated on
>   output.

Comment: Забыл добавить, что надо выводить стоимость заказа. Если использовать вместо `Join` группировку, то стоимость в выборке пропадет.